# my jaxb hello world can run in eclipse but cannot in firefox

Tags: jaxb, japplet

Sorry my bad english, I has a simple japplet that read XML file by JAXB, it can work when testing in Eclipse.

But it show the exception when running in Firefox. what is it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that it is not able to find out the class definition. You are missing the jaxb-impl-X.X.X.jar in your classpath. Where X.X.X means the version of your jar. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I am a Java Dummy, should I pack the jaxb-imp-x.x.x.jar together in my jar. or place it on web server and use jnlp to refer to it?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Why I need to refer a separtate jar? but it work in eclipse, is it related to jaxb in javax.xml......namespace? Where is the offical way to get the jar, is it https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.7/ ?

Comment: I download the jar from jaxb.java.net, there are no namespace 'internal', it only has jaxb-impl\com\sun\xml\bind\v2\model\impl, what can i do